# Laravel 5 on Shared Host Problems

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to deploy my website with laravel on web shared host, not vps.
I have 2 problems here:

1. When I overwrite picture in public folder, the picture won't changed. But if i checked on file manager on cpanel, it actually changed, and when I copy the image address and paste it on other tabs it doesn't changed until I refresh it, the image changed so do in the web.  I'm using Laravel Image Intervention to uploading image, i guess it's don't have problem with library.
   For this problem, I just write 
   `Image::make($imgDriver->getRealPath())->save($pathDriver);` to upload the images. I've tried to use `File::delete` before overwriting the image, but it doesn't solve the problem.
2. The second error is, sometimes i stucked on redirect loop, and I don't know why, all I do was clearing cache to fix it. Do i really need to clean the cache everytime it shows redirect loop. Any other way to solve it?
   I'm using `Route::controller` to route. Is it the problem?

I really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Adding some sample code with what you're doing and how you're doing it would really help explain your problem and make it easier to help.

Comment: @jhdevuk thx for suggestion, now I've added what i've done, thanks

Comment: @SatriaENur Issue 1 sounds like a caching problem, unfortunately it may be impossible to control this on a shared host. For issue 2 it's likely we need a lot more code, perhaps the entire controller involved, or at least the relevant actions, and the lines in the `routes.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your browser is likely caching the image, rather than your hosting provider. If you use Google Chrome, there is a setting to disable cache, which is handy for development. If you want the image to update in your code, append the timestamp to the end of the image in your HTML, e.g. `<img src="my_image.jpg?ts=12345">`. If you use the timestamp when the image was uploaded, it will change everything a new image is uploaded, effectively loading the new version without clearing cache.
2. The redirect look is likely to be a session issue, where you're saving or updating something in the session, causing a redirect loop to occur. This can be painful to debug, but the best thing to do is add debug code to the affected routes / functions to narrow down the cause, e.g. using `dd("i'm here")` to see which block of code could be responsible.